# Parsing JSON Visual Studio C# vs VB

Tags: c#, json, vb.net

I'm having problems parsing some JSon (from an HttpRequest. The received string is :

```
{{
"@odata.context": "https://xxx/$metadata#customers(id,name,nbuys,domestic)",
  "value": [
   {
  "@odata.etag": "W/\"186553045\"",
  "id": "bb1d4f0b",
  "name": "John Smith",
  "nbuys": 5,
  "domestic": true
},
{
  "@odata.etag": "W/\"186553045\"",
  "id": "bgjf4f0a",
  "name": "Jane Doe",
  "nbuys": 8,
  "domestic": false
  }
  ]
}}
```

I successfully deserialize the string in C# using  NewtonSoft:

```
var J  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject( jsonstring);
```

then I can iterate through each customer

```
For Each (item in J.value.Children())   
{
    console.WriteLine(item.name);
 }
```

This works fine, but I need to do the same in Visual Basic. I get the same deserialized object:

```
Dim J as JObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject( jsonstring)
```

but I can't get the following to work

```
Foreach item In J.value.Children()
     console.WriteLine(item.name);

next
```

This doesn't work. I've tried using various J objects without any luck. The only thing I've been able to get is

dim i  as integer = J.Count

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for helping

Comment: If you are using the same Net library in c# and VB.net than code should work.  Indication are the code that is not working is using a different Net.  Try a clean build in VB.Net and make sure you are compiling with same Net as in c#.

Comment: var J  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dim>( jsonstring);    try this please

Comment: Your C# and VB codes differ. In C# `J` is an `Object` while in VB `J` is a `JObject`

Comment: And your supposed C# code isn't valid C# code either... please try to post *precise* code, along with more details than "this doesn't work".

Comment: What you posted is not valid c# code and can not be even compiled. How you can compare it with VB?

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent in VB would be

```vb
Dim J = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring)

For Each item In J("value").Children()
    Console.WriteLine(item.name)
next
```